# socket.IO with useEffect and React Native will not update Redux state multiple times

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, socket.io

I have the same function in my React project and is working perfect but in react native it seem to update the redux state only once and even the useEffect will not update after first call to update the redux. Any idea what can it be?

This is the code

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('check useEffect')
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('check socket', socket.connected);
    });
    socket.on('newDriverAccepted', function (driver) {
        console.log(driver)
        actions.addOrder(driver)
    });
})
```

actions.js

```
export const addOrder = order => {
    return {
        type: "ADD_ORDER",
        payload: order
    };
};
```

reducers.js

```
case "ADD_ORDER":
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        orders: [...state.orders, action.payload]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try with below code

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('check useEffect')
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('check socket', socket.connected);
    });
    socket.on('newDriverAccepted', function (driver) {
        console.log(driver)
        actions.addOrder(driver)
    });
}, [socket, actions, driver])
```

Comment: Please upvote this answer so other can get help. Thank you!